# Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln{(\sin x)}\ \ln{(\cos x})}{\tan x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I need to solve
$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln{(\sin x)}\ \ln{(\cos x})}{\tan x}\ dx
$$

I tried to use symmetric properties of the trigonometric functions as is commonly used to compute
$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln\sin x\ dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2
$$
but never succeeded. (see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227155258/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72243.html) for example)

Comment: Could help that $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(\sin x)) = \frac{1}{\tan x}$ ?

Comment: With the substitution $\ln(\sin x)=u$ you get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \int_{-oo}^{0}  \ln(1-e^{2u}) u \ du$. Then you may use Taylor expansion for $\ln(1-e^{2u})$ and integrate term by term. Does it help?

Comment: Finally, you get $\frac{1}{8} \zeta(3)$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's start out with the substitution $ \displaystyle \ln(\sin x) = u $ and get:
$$\ln(\cos x)=\frac{\ln(1-e^{2u})}{2}$$
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\tan x} \ dx =du$$
that further yields
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(\ln{\sin x})(\ln{\cos x})}{\tan x}dx= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{0}  \ln(1-e^{2u}) u \ du$$

According to Taylor expansion we have 
$$\ln(1-e^{2u})= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{2k+1} \frac{e^{2 k u}}{k}$$
then
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{0}  \ln(1-e^{2u}) u \ du=$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k} \int_{-\infty}^{0} u e^{2ku} \ du =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{k} \frac{-1}{4k^2} = \frac{1}{8} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3}=\frac{1}{8} \zeta(3).$$

**Remark:** the value of $\zeta(3)\approx1.2020569$ is called Apéry's Constant - [see here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AperysConstant.html).

Q.E.D. (Chris)

Comment: It is a nice answer.

Comment: @user78416 sure, wait 30 seconds.

Comment: @user78416 see robjohn's answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330057/how-to-evaluate-i-displaystyle-int-0-pi-2x2-ln-sin-x-ln-cos-xdx

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much

Comment: Hello Chris, I was querying as to whether there is elementary solution without the use of contour integration/ the beta function as I have not delved into such topics yet :)?

Comment: @user78416 my fastest solution uses a clever beta function manipulation, but if you want something elementarily, combine Fourier series with double sums as robjohn did in the first answer. I didn't specifically try to find an elementary proof.

Comment: Can you show me why is this true? $\ln(\cos x)=\frac{\ln(1-e^{2u})}{2}$

Comment: @user137425 $$\ln(\sin x)=u \Rightarrow \sin(x)=e^u \Rightarrow \cos^2(x)=1-e^{2u} \Rightarrow \log(\cos(x))=\frac{\ln(1-e^{2u})}{2}$$

Comment: That's the first integral in a long time I've seen where the Taylor series has been used to expand an improper integral! Nice to see.

Answer (score 24):

Let $u = \sin^2(x)$. Then $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\tan(x)} = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{d\sin(x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}$, $\ln(\sin(x)) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(u)$ and $\ln(\cos(x)) = \frac{1}{2} \ln(1-u)$:
$$
  \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(\sin(x)) \ln(\cos(x))}{\tan(x)} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{8} \int_0^{1} \frac{\ln u}{u} \cdot \ln(1-u) \mathrm{d} u = \left.\frac{1}{8} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} s \mathrm{d} t} \int_0^1 u^{s-1} (1-u)^{t-1} \mathrm{d}u \right|_{s\to 0^+,t=1} = \left.\frac{1}{8} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} s \mathrm{d} t} \frac{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(s+t)} \right|_{s\to 0^+,t=1} 
$$
First differentiate with respect to $t$ and substitute $t=1$:
$$
 \left.\frac{1}{8} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(s+1)}\left( \psi(1) - \psi(s+1)\right)  \right|_{s\to 0^+} = \left.\frac{1}{8} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} s} \frac{\left( \psi(1) - \psi(s+1)\right) }{s} \right|_{s\to 0^+}
$$
Using Taylor series expansion for the digamma function $\psi(s)$ we have:
$$
   \frac{\left( \psi(1) - \psi(s+1)\right) }{s} = -\zeta(2) +  \zeta(3) s + \mathcal{o}(s)
$$
Hence the value of the integral is:
$$
  \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln(\sin(x)) \ln(\cos(x))}{\tan(x)} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{8} \zeta(3)
$$

---

Alternatively you could use $$\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u} = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{u^k}{k+1}$$ and integrate term-wise: $$\int_0^1 u^k \ln(u) \mathrm{d} u \stackrel{u=\exp(-t)}{=} \int_0^\infty t \exp(-t(k+1)) \mathrm{d} t =  -\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$$ which yields the result immediately.

Comment: It looks better the alternative with the series.

Comment: I do not disagree, but I left them in the order they occurred to me.

Comment: Nice solution. Good technique.

Answer (score 10):

Rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln{(\sin x)}\ \ln{(\cos x})}{\tan x}\ dx=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln{(\sin x)}\ \ln{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}}}{\sin x}\cdot\cos x\ dx.
$$
Set $t=\sin x\ \color{red}{\Rightarrow}\ dt=\cos x\ dx$, then we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln{(\sin x)}\ \ln{(\cos x})}{\tan x}\ dx&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\ \ln(1-t^2)}{t}\ dt\\
&=-\frac12\int_0^1\ln t\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^{2n}}{nt}\ dt\tag1\\
&=-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1t^{2n-1}\ln t\ dt\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\tag2\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}}.
\end{align}

---

**Notes :**

$[1]\ \ $Use Maclaurin series for natural logarithm: $\displaystyle\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\ $ for $|x|<1$.

$[2]\ \ $[$\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(\alpha+1)^{n+1}}\ $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/877844/123277) for $  n=0,1,2,\cdots$

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}
>      \over \tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}\over \tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ =\ \arcsin\pars{t}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{\root{1 - t^{2}}} \over t\,/\root{1 - t^{2}}}\,
{\dd t \over \root{1 - t^{2}}}
\\[5mm]= &\
\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t^{2}} \over t}\,\dd t =
\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t^{1/2}}\ln\pars{1 - t}\over
t^{1/2}}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]
= &\
{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
=-\,{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{t} \over t}\,\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t
=-\,{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t
={1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm Li}_{3}'\pars{t}\,\dd t
={1 \over 8}\,{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{1} =
\bbox[10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\zeta\pars{3}}}
\approx 0.1503
\end{align}

> $\ds{{\rm Li}_{\rm s}\pars{z}}$ is a
>   [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm): I  used some properties of them as reported in the cited link.
>   $\ds{\zeta\pars{s}}$ is the [Riemann Zeta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: Very nice answer. +1

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks. I'm ${\rm Li}$ fan.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\log(\cos(x)) \log(\sin(x))}{\tan(x)} \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\log\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) \log\left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)}{x} \, \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \tag{1} \\[1ex]
&= \frac14 \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^2(x^2+1)-\log(x^2)\log(x^2+1)}{x} \, \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \\[1ex]
&= \frac18 \int_0^\infty \frac{\log^2(x+1)-\log(x)\log(x+1)}{x(1+x)} \, dx \tag{2} \\[1ex]
&= \frac18 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\log^2(x+1)}{x} - \frac{\log(x)\log(x+1)}x\right) \, dx \tag{3} \\[1ex]
&= \frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(x+1)}x \, dx - \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x+1)\log(x)}{x+1} \, dx \tag{4} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}n \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \log(x) \, dx + \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n H_n \int_0^1 x^n \log(x) \, dx \tag{5} \\[1ex]
&= -\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3} + \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(n+1)^2} \tag{4} \\[1ex]
&= \boxed{\frac{\zeta(3)}8} \tag{6}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $x\mapsto\arctan(x)$
- $(2)$ : substitute $x\mapsto\sqrt x$
- $(3)$ : split up the integral at $x=1$; substitute $x\mapsto\frac1x$ in the integral over $[1,\infty)$; partial fractions
- $(4)$ : integrate by parts
- $(5)$ : recall the power series $-\log(1-x)=\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}n$ and $-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n\ge1} H_n x^n$, where $H_n$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ harmonic number
- $(6)$ : see e.g. [section $7$](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf) for a contour-integration method to evaluating the Euler sum; I'm sure there are more efficient means