# How to calculate $I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin y)\ln(\cos y)}{\sin y\cos y}dy$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms, problem-solving

How do I integrate this guy? I've been stuck on this for hours..

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin y)\ln(\cos y)}{\sin y\cos y}dy$$

Comment: Is it really $dx$, and not $dy$?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/188921/11069) earlier question is very relevant.

Comment: @Sasha, I enjoyed your answer. Though the calculation becomes slightly harder in this problem as the singularity arises for both $z$ and $w$ for $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial w}\beta(z, w)$, they all cancel out and yield the correct answer.

Comment: The integral looks pretty sane to me. But really, we prefer to avoid subjective titles.

Answer (score 15):

Let $x = \sin^2y$.
(It seems we've started like @Sasha [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188931/26872) and like @sos440.)
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=& \frac{1}{16} \int_0^1 dx\, \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x(1-x)} \\
    &=& \frac{1}{16} \int_0^1 dx\, \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}
    + \underbrace{\frac{1}{16} \int_0^1 dx\, \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}}_{x\to 1-x}
    \qquad (\textrm{partial fractions}) \\
    &=& \frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 dx\, \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{x}
    \qquad (\textrm{integral linked above}) \\
    &=& \frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 dx\, \frac{\log(x)}{x} \left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}\right)
    \qquad (\textrm{Taylor expansion for }\log(1-x) ) \\
    &=& -\frac{1}{8} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1} \underbrace{\int_0^1 dx\, x^k \log x}_{-1/(k+1)^2} 
    \qquad (\textrm{standard integral involving log}) \\
    &=& \frac{1}{8} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^3} \\
    &=& \frac{\zeta(3)}{8}. 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

*Addendum*: 
Note that $\csc(y)\sec(y) = \cot y + \tan y$. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} dy\,
    \frac{\ln(\sin y)\ln(\cos y)}{\sin y\cos y} \\
    &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} dy\,
    \frac{\ln(\sin y)\ln(\cos y)}{\tan y}
    + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} dy\,
    \frac{\ln(\sin y)\ln(\cos y)}{\cot y}}_{y\to \pi/2-y} \\
    &=& \int_{0}^{\pi/2} dy\,
    \frac{\ln(\sin y)\ln(\cos y)}{\tan y}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
This is exactly the integral linked above.

Comment: I love this answer! (And of course +1 upvote.) My answer, compared to this concise and brilliant solution, seems just a dull sledgehammer. :(

Comment: @oen, +1, very nice solution.

Comment: @oen +1. Neat.${}$

Comment: @oen: by far this is the most brilliant answer! (+1) :D

Comment: @Chris'ssister: You go too far, but thanks. By the way, I like your [substitution](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/189174/26872). (+1)

Comment: @oen: thank you! Well, I simply respect the truth! Your solution is awesome: easy, short, fast!

Answer (score 14):

Let $\sin(y) = t$. Recall that $\cos^2(y) = 1-t^2$. Then $\cos(y) dy = dt$. Hence,
$$I = \dfrac14 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(\sin(y)) \ln(\cos^2(y)) \cos(y) dy}{\sin(y) \cos^2(y)}$$
$$4I = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(t) \ln(1-t^2) dt}{t (1-t^2)}$$
$$\dfrac{\ln(t) \ln(1-t^2)}{t (1-t^2)} = -\dfrac{\ln(t)}{t(1-t^2)} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{t^{2k}}k = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln(t)}{(1-t^2)} \dfrac{t^{2k-1}}k$$
$$\dfrac{\ln(t)}{(1-t^2)} \dfrac{t^{2k-1}}k = \dfrac1k \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}t^{2k+2\ell-1} \ln(t)$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{\ln(t) \ln(1-t^2)}{t (1-t^2)} = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1k\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}t^{2k+2\ell-1} \ln(t)$$
Recall that $$\int_0^1 t^m \log(t) dt = -\dfrac1{(m+1)^2}$$
Hence, $$4I = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1k \dfrac1{(2k+2 \ell)^2} = \dfrac14 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1k \dfrac1{(k+\ell)^2} = \dfrac14 2 \zeta(3)$$
Hence, $$I = \dfrac{\zeta(3)}8$$

**EDIT**

Consider the sum
$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1k\dfrac1{(k+l)^2}$$
We have that
$$S = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=k}^{\infty} \dfrac1k\dfrac1{l^2} = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^l \dfrac1k\dfrac1{l^2}}_{\text{Change order of summation}} = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_l}{l^2}$$
Also, note that
$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1k\dfrac1{k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1k\dfrac1{(k+l)^2} = \zeta(3) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1k\dfrac1{(k+l)^2}$$

Now let us evaluate the second sum in the above line.(To evaluate this, we follow the technique @sos440 has in his answer.)

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{(k+l)^2}
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{(k+l)^2} + \frac{1}{l} \frac{1}{(k+l)^2} \right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{kl(k+l)}
 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \frac{1}{l} - \frac{1}{k+l}\right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{k}}{k^2}
\end{align*}

Hence, we have $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^2} = \zeta(3) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{k}}{k^2}$$
This gives us $$S = 2 \zeta(3)$$

Comment: Why does the last double sum equal $2\zeta(3)$?

Comment: @EricNaslund Have added the reason.

Comment: @EricNaslund Thanks for asking the question. Initially, I just evaluated it using wolfram-alpha, hoping that some trivial algebraic manipulation could give the answer. But it wasn't as trivial as I thought. Thanks.

Comment: @EricNaslund The fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k}{k^2} = 2 \zeta(3)$ is an instance of the [sum conjecture](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pjm/1102636166) mentioned in the paper, equation $1$ and page $281$, being true for $n=3$ and $k=2$. Just wanted to share this nice information with you, in case you were not aware of it.

Answer (score 11):

I will assume that your $dx$ is indeed a type of $dy$, otherwise the answer is clear.

Let $t = \sin^2 y$. Then $dt = 2 \sin y \cos y \, dy$ and we have

$$I = \frac{1}{16} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log t \log(1-t)}{t(1-t)} \, dt. $$

Then thanks to the Taylor expansion

$$ \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n-1}}{n}, $$

we have

\begin{align*}
I
&= -\frac{1}{16} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log t}{1-t} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n-1}}{n} \, dt
 = -\frac{1}{16} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{n-1} \log t}{1-t} \, dt \\
&= -\frac{1}{16} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} t^{n+m-1} \log t \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{16} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(m+n)^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{16}\zeta(3) + \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(m+n)^2}.
\end{align*}

Now we focus on the double summation in the last line. By interchanging the role of $m$ and $n$,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(m+n)^2}
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(m+n)^2} + \frac{1}{m} \frac{1}{(m+n)^2} \right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{mn(m+n)}
 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m+n}\right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^2}
\end{align*}

To this end, it is natural to consider the following power series.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^2} x^n. $$

Associated with this series we easily observe that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n x^n = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}. $$

Thus we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n} x^n
&= -\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log(1-t)}{t(1-t)} \, dt
 = -\int_{0}^{x} \left\{ \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} + \frac{\log(1-t)}{1-t} \right\} \, dt \\
&= \mathrm{Li}_2 (x) + \frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-x),
\end{align*}

where $\mathrm{Li}_s (x)$ is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) defined by

$$ \mathrm{Li}_s (x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^s}. $$

Thus we must have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^2} x^n
&= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\left\{ \mathrm{Li}_2 (t) + \frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-t) \right\} \, dt \\
&= \mathrm{Li}_3 (x) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log^2(1-t)}{t} \, dt.
\end{align*}

Let $I(x)$ denote the latter integral. Then by integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
2I(x)
= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log^2(1-t)}{t} \, dt
= -\mathrm{Li}_2(x) \log(1-x) - \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_2(t)}{1-t} \, dt.
\end{align*}

But we know that $\mathrm{Li}_2 (x)$ satisfies the Euler reflection formula

$$ \mathrm{Li}_2 (x) + \mathrm{Li}_2 (1-x) = \zeta(2) - \log x \log (1-x), $$

which is easily proved by differentiation both sides with respect to $x$. Thus we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_2 (t)}{1-t} \; dt
& = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1-t} \left[ \zeta(2) - \log t \log (1-t) - \mathrm{Li}_2 (1-t) \right] \; dt \\
& = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\zeta(2) - \mathrm{Li}_2 (1-t)}{1-t} \; dt - \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log t \log (1-t)}{1-t} \; dt.
\end{align*}

But the fist integral is easily calculated as we can find its antiderivative:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\zeta(2) - \mathrm{Li}_2 (1-t)}{1-t} \; dt
&= \left[ -\zeta(2)\log(1-t) + \mathrm{Li}_{3} (1-t) \right]_{0}^{x} \\
&= -\zeta(2) \log(1-x) + \mathrm{Li}_{3}(1-x) - \zeta(3).
\end{align*}

The second integral reduces to a formula involving $I(x)$:

\begin{align*}
-\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\log t \log (1-t)}{1-t} \; dt 
&= \left[ \frac{1}{2} \log^2 (1-t) \log t \right]_{0}^{x} - I(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log^2 (1-x) \log x - I(x).
\end{align*}

From this calculation, we obtain a closed form for $I(x)$ as follows:

$$ I(x) = \zeta(3) - \mathrm{Li}_3 (1-x) + \{ \zeta(2) - \mathrm{Li}_2 (x) \} \log (1 - x) - \frac{1}{2} \log^2 (1-x) \log x. $$

Plugging $x = 1$, we then have

$$ I(1) = \zeta(3).$$

Therefore we have

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^2} = 2 \zeta(3)$$

and hence

\begin{align*}
I = \frac{1}{16}\zeta(3) + \frac{1}{16} \zeta(3) = \frac{1}{8}\zeta(3).
\end{align*}

Comment: +1. Though evaluation of $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1k \dfrac1{(k+l)^2}$$ could be simplified a lot. See my post.

Answer (score 3):

According to Mathematica, $$I=\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}$$where $\zeta$ is the [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function). (See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Integral) about the integral). This is approximately 0.150257.