# Integral $\int_0^\pi \theta^2 \ln^2\big(2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\big)d \theta$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, contour-integration

I am trying to calculate

$$
I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \theta^2 \ln^2\big(2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\big)d \theta=\frac{11\pi^4}{180}=\frac{11\zeta(4)}{2}.
$$
Note, we can expand the log in the integral to obtain three interals, one trivial, the other 2 are not so easy, any ideas?  We will use
$$
\left( \ln 2 +\ln \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \right)^2=\ln^2(2)+\ln^2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+2\ln (2)\ln \cos\big(\frac{\theta}{2}\big)
$$ and re-write I as
$$
\pi I=\ln^2(2)\int_0^\pi \theta^2d\theta  +\int_0^\pi\theta^2 \ln^2 \cos \frac{\theta}{2}d\theta+2\ln 2 \int_0^\pi\theta^2 \ln \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}d\theta.
$$
Simplfying this further by using $y=\theta/2$ we obtain
$$
\pi I=\frac{\pi^3\ln^2(2)}{3}+16\ln(2)\int_0^{\pi/2} y^2 \ln \cos (y) dy+8\int_0^{\pi/2} y^2 \ln^2 \cos (y) dy
$$
Any Idea how to approach these two integrals? I know that 
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \cos y dy= \frac{-\pi\ln(2)}{2}\approx -1.08879
$$
but I am unsure how to use that here.  I do not think partial integration will work, Also the Riemann Zeta function is given by 
$$
\zeta(4)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}.
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330057/how-to-evaluate-i-displaystyle-int-0-pi-2x2-ln-sin-x-ln-cos-xdx/331222#331222
(See sos440's answer).

Comment: @FelixFelicis This is very related, and you may enjoy this a lot!: http://www.math.uwo.ca/~dborwein/cv/zeta4.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{I \equiv
    {1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\theta^{2}\ln^{2}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta \over 2}}
     \,\dd\theta = {11\pi^{4} \over 180} = {11 \over 2}\,\zeta\pars{4}}$

> \begin{align}
> I&={1 \over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\theta^{2}
> \ln^{2}\pars{2\root{1 + \cos\pars{\theta} \over 2}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2\pi}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> \bracks{-\ln^{2}\pars{z}}\ln^{2}\pars{\root{2}\root{1 + {z^{2} + 1 \over 2z}}}\,
> {\dd z \over \ic z}
> \\[3mm]&={\ic \over 2\pi}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> \ln^{2}\pars{z}\ln^{2}\pars{z + 1 \over z^{1/2}}\,{\dd z \over z}
> \\[3mm]&={\ic \over 2\pi}\lim_{\mu \to -1 \atop \nu \to 0}
> \partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> z^{\mu}\pars{z + 1 \over z^{1/2}}^{\nu}\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&={\ic \over 2\pi}\lim_{\mu \to -1 \atop \nu \to 0}
> \partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}z^{\mu - \nu/2}\pars{z + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd z
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\pars{1}
> \end{align}

The integration in $\pars{1}$ is given by:
\begin{align}
&\int_{\verts{z} = 1}
z^{\mu - \nu/2}\pars{z + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&=-\int_{-1}^{0}\pars{-x}^{\mu - \nu/2}\expo{\ic\pi\pars{\mu - \nu/2}}
\pars{x + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd x
-\int_{0}^{-1}\pars{-x}^{\mu - \nu/2}\expo{-\ic\pi\pars{\mu - \nu/2}}
\pars{x + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\expo{\ic\pi\pars{\mu - \nu/2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - \nu/2}
\pars{-x + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd x
+\expo{-\ic\pi\pars{\mu - \nu/2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - \nu/2}
\pars{-x + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=2\ic\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{{\nu \over 2} - \mu}}
{\rm B}\pars{\mu - {\nu \over 2} + 1,\nu + 1}\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = \int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{y - 1}\,\dd t}$,
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ \Re\pars{x} > 0,\ \Re\pars{y} > 0~}}$ is the
[Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

> With $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$, $\ds{I}$ is reduced to:
>   $$
> I=-\,{1 \over \pi}\lim_{\mu \to -1 \atop \nu \to 0}
> \partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\bracks{%
> \sin\pars{\pi\bracks{{\nu \over 2} - \mu}}
> {\rm B}\pars{\mu - {\nu \over 2} + 1,\nu + 1}}
> $$

Since $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y}=
{\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y} \over \Gamma\pars{x + y}}}$
( $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
[GammaFunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) ):
\begin{align}
I&=-\,{1 \over \pi}\
\lim_{\mu \to -1 \atop \nu \to 0}
\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\bracks{%
\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{{\nu \over 2} - \mu}}
{\Gamma\pars{\mu - \nu/2 + 1}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}
 \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu/2 + 2}}}
\\[3mm]&=-\
\overbrace{\lim_{\mu \to -1 \atop \nu \to 0}
\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\bracks{%
{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}
 \over \Gamma\pars{\nu/2 - \mu}\Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu/2 + 2}}}}
^{\ds{=\ -\,{11\pi^{4} \over 180}}}
\end{align}
where we used the identity
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}\Gamma\pars{1 - z} = {\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}}}$

> Then,
>   $$
> I \equiv
> \color{#00f}{\large%
> {1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\theta^{2}\ln^{2}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta \over 2}}    \,\dd\theta}
> = \color{#00f}{\large{11\pi^{4} \over 180} = {11 \over 2}\,\zeta\pars{4}}
> $$

Comment: This is an excellent solution.  Thanks a lot Felix Marin.  I had thought I had commented earlier on this.  Sorry for the delay, this answer is GREAT. Nice Integral

Comment: @Jeff Thanks a lot. You're welcome.

Comment: you may appreciate this: http://www.math.uwo.ca/~dborwein/cv/zeta4.pdf

Comment: @Integrals That link is very helpful. Manipulation of Harmonic Numbers are always somehow tricky and that paper has a lot about them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One way to go about this is to use the identity:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{p-1}(x)\cos(ax)dx=\frac{\pi}{2^{p}}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(p)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+p+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{p-a+1}{2}\right)}....(1)$$

Then, diff this twice w.r.t 'a', and let a=0.

Then, diff twice w.r.t p and let p=1.

The diffing on the right side may be a little tedious, but get tech to do it.

diffing once w.r.t p will give you $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^{2}\ln(\cos(x))dx=\frac{-\pi^{3}}{24}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi}{3}\zeta(3)$$.

Then, diff again to get the integral in question.

a fun way to go about evaluating this integral is to use contours.

consider $$f(z)=zlog^{3}(1+e^{2iz})$$ over a rectangular contour with vertices $$-\frac{\pi}{2}, \;\ \frac{\pi}{2}, \;\ \frac{\pi}{2}+Ri, \;\ \frac{-\pi}{2}+Ri$$, with quarter-circle indents around $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$.

A good while back, Nick Strehle wrote up a nice post on this method of evaluating log-trig integrals via residues. It is on the site somewhere if you nose around.