# Integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} \theta^2 \log ^4(2\cos \theta) d\theta =\frac{33\pi^7}{4480}+\frac{3\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}  \theta^2 \log ^4(2\cos \theta) d\theta =\frac{33\pi^7}{4480}+\frac{3\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3).
$$
Note $\zeta(3)$ is given by
$$
\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}.
$$
I have a previous post related to this except the logarithm power is squared and not to the 4th power.  If you are interested in seeing this result go here: [Integral $\int_0^\pi \theta^2 \ln^2\big(2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\big)d \theta$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699746/integral-int-0-pi-theta2-ln2-big2-cos-frac-theta2-bigd-theta).  However, I am wondering how to calculate the result shown above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

From Table of Integrals, Series, and Products Seventh Edition by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik equation $3.631\ (9)$ we have

> $$
> \int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\cos^{n-1}x\cos ax\ dx=\frac{\pi}{2^n n\ \operatorname{B}\left(\frac{n+a+1}{2},\frac{n-a+1}{2}\right)}
> $$

**Proof**

Integrating $(1+z)^p z^q$, for $p,q\ge0$, in the $z=u+iv$ plane around the contour bounded by the $u$-axis from $-1$ to $1$ and the upper semicircle of unit radius yields
$$
\int_{-1}^1(1+z)^p z^q\ dz=-i\int_0^\pi\left(1+e^{it}\right)^p e^{i(q+1)t}\ dt,
$$
since $(1+z)^p z^q$ is holomorphic within and continuous on and within the given contour. The imaginary part of the RHS is
$$
\Im\left[-i\int_0^\pi\left(1+e^{it}\right)^p e^{i(q+1)t}\ dt\right]=-\int_0^\pi\left(2\cos\frac t2\right)^p \cos bt\ dt,
$$
where $b=q+\frac12p+1$. The LHS integral is equal to
$$
\int_{0}^1(1+u)^p u^q\ du+e^{i\pi q}\int_{0}^1(1-u)^p u^q\ du
$$
of which the imaginary part is
\begin{align}
\operatorname{B}\left(p+1,q+1\right)\sin\pi q&=-\frac{\Gamma\left(p+1\right)\Gamma\left(q+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(p+q+2\right)}\sin\pi q\\
&=-\frac{\Gamma\left(p+1\right)\Gamma\left(b-\frac12p\right)}{\Gamma\left(b+\frac12p+1\right)}\sin\pi \left(b-\frac12p\right)\\
&=-\frac{\pi\Gamma\left(p+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac12p+b\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac12p-b\right)}.
\end{align}
Final step is setting $t=2x$, $p=n-1$, and $a=2b$. $\qquad\color{blue}{\mathbb{Q.E.D.}}$

---

Thus
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\theta^2\ln^4(2\cos \theta)\ d\theta&=\lim_{n\to5}\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\partial^6}{\partial n^4\partial a^2}\left[\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}(2\cos \theta)^{n-1}\cos a\theta\ d\theta\right]\\
&=\lim_{n\to5}\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\partial^6}{\partial n^4\partial a^2}\left[\frac{\pi}{2 n\ \operatorname{B}\left(\frac{n+a+1}{2},\frac{n-a+1}{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\frac{33\pi^7}{4480}+\frac{3\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Differentiating the identity is indeed quite a nice way of evaluating the integral. (+1)

Comment: @SuperAbound But it's tedious. Thanks, +1 too.

Answer (score 8):

Note that
$$\ln(1+e^{i2x})=\ln(2\cos{x})+ix$$
Raise both sides to the fourth power and extract the real part. This yields
\begin{align}
\Re\ln^4(1+e^{i2x})=\ln^4(2\cos{x})-6x^2\ln^2(2\cos{x})+x^4
\end{align}
We first have to calculate $\displaystyle\int^{\pi/2}_0x^4\ln^2(2\cos{x}) \ {\rm d}x$. Squaring the above identity and extracting the real part gives
$$\Re\ln^2(1+e^{i2x})=\ln^2(2\cos{x})-x^2$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0x^4\ln^2(2\cos{x}) \ {\rm d}x
&=\Re\int^{\pi/2}_0x^4\ln^2(1+e^{i2x}) \ {\rm d}x+\frac{\pi^7}{896}\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{896}+\frac{1}{32}\Im\int^{1}_0\frac{\ln^4{(-z)}\ln^2(1-z)}{z}{\rm d}z\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{896}+\frac{\pi}{8}\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3{z}\ln^2(1-z)}{z}{\rm d}z-\frac{\pi^3}{8}\int^1_0\frac{\ln{z}\ln^2(1-z)}{z}{\rm d}z\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{896}-\frac{\pi}{16}\sum^\infty_{n=1}H_n\int^1_0z^n\ln^4{z} \ {\rm d}z+\frac{\pi^3}{8}\sum^\infty_{n=1}H_n\int^1_0z^n\ln^2{z} \ {\rm d}z\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{896}-\frac{3\pi}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^5}+\frac{\pi^3}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^3}\\
&=\frac{5\pi^7}{8064}+\frac{3\pi}{4}\zeta^2(3)
\end{align}
where I have used the result
$$2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^q}=(q+2)\zeta(q+1)-\sum^{q-2}_{j=1}\zeta(j+1)\zeta(q-j)$$
which can be easily derived by integrating $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{(\gamma+\psi(-z))^2}{z^q}$ along an infinitely large square.

---

Moving on to the actual integral,
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0x^2\ln^4(2\cos{x}) \ {\rm d}x
&=\frac{\pi^7}{384}+\frac{9\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)+\Re\int^{\pi/2}_0x^2\ln^4(1+e^{i2x}) \ {\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{384}+\frac{9\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{1}{8}\Im\int^{1}_0\frac{\ln^2(-z)\ln^4(1-z)}{z}\ {\rm d}z\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{384}+\frac{9\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{\pi}{4}\int^{1}_0\frac{\ln^4{z}\ln(1-z)}{1-z}\ {\rm d}z\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{384}+\frac{9\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)+\frac{\pi}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=1}H_n\int^1_0z^n\ln^4{z} \ {\rm d}z\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{384}+\frac{9\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)+6\pi\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^5}\\
&=\frac{\pi^7}{384}+\frac{9\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)+\frac{\pi^7}{210}-3\pi\zeta^2(3)\\
&=\frac{33\pi^7}{4480}+\frac{3\pi}{2}\zeta^2(3)
\end{align}
as was to be shown.

---

Just for fun, here is a derivation of
$$2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^q}=(q+2)\zeta(q+1)-\sum^{q-2}_{j=1}\zeta(j+1)\zeta(q-j)$$ Consider $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{(\gamma+\psi(-z))^2}{z^q}$. At the positive integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{1}{z^q(z-n)^2}+\frac{2H_n}{z^q(z-n)}\right]\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^q}-q\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{q+1}}\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^q}-q\zeta(q+1)\\
\end{align}
At zero,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}(f,0)
&=[z^{q-1}]\left(\frac{1}{z}-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\zeta(k+1)z^k\right)^2\\
&=[z^{q-1}]\left(-2\sum^\infty_{k=1}\zeta(k+1)z^{k-1}+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\sum^k_{j=1}\zeta(j+1)\zeta(k-j+2)z^{k+1}\right)\\
&=-2\zeta(q+1)+\sum^{q-2}_{j=1}\zeta(j+1)\zeta(q-j)
\end{align}
where I have removed the first (irrelevant) term and used the Cauchy product in the second equality. Since the sum of the residues is zero, we conclude
$$2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^q}=(q+2)\zeta(q+1)-\sum^{q-2}_{j=1}\zeta(j+1)\zeta(q-j)$$

Comment: unique and well explained.

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
     ={33\pi^{7} \over 4480} + {3\pi \over 2}\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}%
> \theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
> =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2\root{1 + \cos\pars{2\theta} \over 2}}
> \,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{\pi}
> \theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2^{1/2}\root{1 + \cos\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
> ={1 \over 16}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
> \theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2^{1/2}\root{1 + \cos\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 16}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> \bracks{-\ic\ln\pars{z}}^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2^{1/2}\root{1 + {z^{2} + 1 \over 2z}}}
> \,{\dd z \over \ic z}
> \\[3mm]&={\ic \over 16}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> \ln^{2}\pars{z}\ln^{4}\pars{z + 1 \over z^{1/2}}\,{\dd z \over z}
> \\[3mm]&={\ic \over 16}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0 \atop \nu\ \to\ 0}\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[4]{}{\nu}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> z^{\mu}\pars{z + 1 \over z^{1/2}}^{\nu}\,{\dd z \over z} 
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}%
\theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
={\ic \over 16}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0 \atop \nu\ \to\ 0}
\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[4]{}{\nu}\color{#00f}{%
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
z^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}\pars{z + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd z} 
$$

> \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{%
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1\atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi}}
> z^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}\pars{z + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd z}
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{-1}^{0}\pars{-x}^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}
> \exp\pars{\bracks{\mu - {\nu \over 2} - 1}\pi\ic}\pars{x + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=\!}-\int_{0}^{-1}\pars{-x}^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}
> \exp\pars{-\bracks{\mu - {\nu \over 2} - 1}\pi\ic}\pars{x + 1}^{\nu}\,\dd x
> \\[1cm]&=\exp\pars{\bracks{\mu - {\nu \over 2}}\pi\ic}
> \int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{\nu}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&-\exp\pars{-\bracks{\mu - {\nu \over 2}}\pi\ic}
> \int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{\nu}\,\dd x
> \\[1cm]&=2\ic\sin\pars{\bracks{\mu - {\nu \over 2}}\pi}
> \int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - \nu/2 - 1}\pars{1 - x}^{\nu}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=2\ic\sin\pars{\bracks{\mu - {\nu \over 2}}\pi}\,
> {\Gamma\pars{\mu - \nu/2}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu/2 + 1}}
> =2\pi\ic\,
> {\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}
> \over \Gamma\pars{1 - \mu + \nu/2}\Gamma\pars{1 + \mu + \nu/2 }}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}%
\theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
=-\,{\pi \over 8}\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0 \atop \nu\ \to\ 0}
\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\partiald[4]{}{\nu}{\nu \choose \mu + \nu/2} 
$$
The derivatives and the limits are a formidable task which we can evaluate with a [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system):
$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\theta^{2}\ln^{4}\pars{2\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
={33\pi^{7} \over 4480} + {3\pi \over 2}\,\zeta^{2}\pars{3}}
\approx {\tt 29.0568}
$$