# Rational approximation of $\pi$ by recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, recursion, rational-numbers, pi

I wonder if the following result is already known and may be considered as interesting : let $\mathcal{C}$ be the real algebra of continuous functions $f:\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbf{R}$, $T:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}$ the map defined by
$$
T\left(f\right)\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)\left(2-\left(1+x^2\right)f\left(x\right)\right)
$$
$\left(f_n\right)$ the sequence of $\mathcal{C}$ defined by
$$
f_n=
\begin{cases}
T\left(f_{n-1}\right) & \text{if } n>0\\
1/2 & \text{if } n=0
\end{cases}
$$
and $\left(I_n\right)$ the real sequence defined by $I_n=\int_0^1 f_n\left(x\right) \, dx$. One has
$$
\forall n\in\mathbf{N} \qquad 0 \leq \frac{\pi}{4} - I_n \leq 2^{-2^n}
$$
and
$$
\forall n\in\mathbf{N} \qquad I_n = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{2^k}{\left(2k+1\right)\binom{2k}{k}}
$$

Comment: See the [Arctangent part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Arctangent) on the Wikipedia page for approximations of $\pi$.

Comment: @prets: thank you. This recursive approach yields $S_{2^n-1}$, where $S_n$ is the partial sum of the expansion in the link. I wonder if this is remarkable/intersting or not.

Comment: The sequence $f_n$ is an approximation from below of $\dfrac{1}{1 + x^2}$ which converges termwise to its power series around $x = 0$, so this is really the exact same thing as $\arctan(1) = \pi/4$ and $\dfrac{d}{d x} \arctan(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

Comment: But here, the distance between the limit and $f_n$ is dominated by $2^{-2^n}$. Maybe I don't understand your remark.

Comment: The constant term of $f_n$ is $1 - 2^{-2^n}$, which is where that bound comes from (the constant term of the power series of $\dfrac{1}{1 + x^2}$ around $x = 0$ is $1$, so the difference is the $2^{-2^n}$ you're observing).

Comment: More generally, one can show : $$\forall n\in\mathbf{N},\forall x\in\left[0,1\right] \qquad f_n \left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \left(\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right)^k$$

Comment: Take $x=1$ in the first formula given in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1990577/305862) by Ron Gordon and the reference herein (reference found using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Comment: @Jean Marie (Monier ? I'm french) : thank you for the reference. I am aware of these identities. What I would like to underline here is : 1. the speed of convergence and 2. the simple aspect of this recursion. As a non-specialist, I ask myself if this would have any interest in a computanional point of view. I am also aware that they are more efficient algorithms to approach $\pi$. But maybe this is nothing but a "gourmandise".

Comment: 1) Happy to meet fellow citizens ! (from which region ?) 2) I am not Jean-Marie Monnier, though I know him. My family name is Becker 3) Your question is interesting.

Comment: As a new user, I don't know how to chat with other users.

Comment: If I may ask, where are you located ? I am in Pau. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I live in the "Loire Valley" : Tours.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I_n = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{2^k}{\left(2k+1\right)\binom{2k}{k}}=\frac \pi 4-J_n$$
$$J_n=\frac{2^{2^n-1}}{\left(2^{n+1}+1\right) \binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}}\,\,\, _2F_1\left(1,2^n+1;2^n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$J_n < \frac{2^{2^n}}{\left(2^{n+1}+1\right) \binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}}$$
$$\log \big[-\log (J_n)\big]=n \log (2)-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{5
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log \left(-\log \left(\frac{J_{n+1}}{J_n}\right)\right) \sim n\log(2)-\frac 13$$

**Edit**

The first $I_n$ form the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{16}{21},\frac{11776}{15015},
   \frac{208481288192}{265447707525},\frac{3374092439600157908008
   96}{429602792188525533252675}\right\}$$