# Is there a nice closed form to $\int_0^{\pi/2} (\log \sin x)^n\text{ d}x$ for $n\in \Bbb{Q},n\gt 1$?

Tags: integration

For $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\log \sin x)^n\text{ d}x=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}B^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Can we extend that result a bit further, to $n\in \Bbb{Q},n\gt 1?$

Comment: I don't know what $B^{(n)}$ is, but does the formula make sense for all $n\in Q$? Did you plug in some values to check if it still holds?

Comment: $B^(n)$ is the derivative of the Beta function

Comment: It seems to me that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\log \sin x)^n\text{ d}x=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}B^{(n)}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your totally right, mistake of writing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the change of variables $t= \sin(x) $ to get
$$ I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n t}  {\sqrt{1- t^2}} dt$$
Then make another change of variables $t^2=u$ and simplify . Then see
[my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330057/how-to-evaluate-i-displaystyle-int-0-pi-2x2-ln-sin-x-ln-cos-x-mathrm/332041#332041) to finish the problem.