# Double summation $\sum_{m,n=1\, m\neq n}^\infty{\frac{m^2+n^2}{mn(m^2-n^2)^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

As a follow to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2982316/357106) I came across the double sum $$\sum_{m,n=1\, m\neq n}^\infty{\frac{m^2+n^2}{mn(m^2-n^2)^2}}.$$
But unfortunately I do not have skills in techniques to handle double summation .

Help appreciated.

I've made some research in MSE and found several questions which could be helpful:

[1) $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{(-1)^{m-n}}{(m^2-n^2)^2}=-\frac{17\pi^4}{1440}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1892241/357106)

[2) $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{ 1}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}=\frac{\pi^6}{12960}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1294185/357106)

[3) $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2k^2(n+k)^2}=  \frac{1}{3}\zeta(6)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1007926/357106)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The double summation is equal to
>   $$\frac{11\zeta(4)}{8}=\frac{11\pi^4}{720}.$$

Note that
$$\frac{m^2+n^2}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}=
\frac{1}{2 mn(m+n)^2}+
\frac{1}{2 mn(m-n)^2}.$$
Now consider the Tornheim double sums:
$$T(a,b,c)= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{m^an^b(m+n)^c}.$$
Then
$$ \sum_{m,n=1\, m\neq n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{mn(m+n)^2}=T(1,1,2)-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4m^4}=T(1,1,2)-\frac{\zeta(4)}{4},$$
$$\begin{align} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} 
\frac{1}{mn(m-n)^2}
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{mn(m-n)^2}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{nk^2(n+k)}=T(1,2,1)\end{align}$$
and again
$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} 
\frac{1}{mn(m-n)^2}=T(1,2,1).$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}\sum_{m,n=1\, m\neq n}^{\infty}{\frac{m^2+n^2}{mn(m^2-n^2)^2}}
&=\frac{T(1,1,2)-\zeta(4)/4}{2} +T(1,2,1)\\
&=\frac{11\zeta(4)}{8}
\end{align}$$
where we used 
$$T(1,1,2)=\zeta(4)/2\quad,\quad T(1,2,1)=5\zeta(4)/2$$
(see page 31 in [The evaluation of Tornheim double sums](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0557)).

Comment: Nice solution. Interesting reference. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

From Robert Z's answer, we have
$$\frac{m^2+n^2}{mn(m^2-n^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2mn(m+n)^2}+\frac{1}{2mn(m-n)^2}.$$
Hence, the required sum
$$S=\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m\neq n}}}\frac{1}{mn(m^2-n^2)^2}$$
can be split into two parts:
$$S_1=\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m\neq n}}}\frac{1}{2mn(m+n)^2}=\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb N_1}\frac{1}{2mn(m+n)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{8n^4}$$
and
$$S_2=\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m\neq n}}}\frac{1}{2mn(m-n)^2}=\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m>n}}}\frac{1}{2mn(m-n)^2}+\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m< n}}}\frac{1}{2mn(n-m)^2}.$$

Let's look at $S_2$ more closely.  The first summand satisfies
$$\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m>n}}}\frac{1}{2mn(m-n)^2}=\sum_{m,k\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2m(m+k)k^2},$$
where $k=m-n$.  The second summand satisfies
$$\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m>n}}}\frac{1}{2mn(m-n)^2}=\sum_{n,l\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2(n+l)nl^2},$$
where $l=n-m$.  Therefore, we can rename the dummy variables and get
\begin{align}S_2&=\sum_{m,k\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2m(m+k)k^2}+\sum_{n,l\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2(n+l)nl^2}\\&=\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2mn^2(m+n)}+\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2m^2n(m+n)}.\end{align}
So,
$$S_2=\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\left(\frac{1}{2mn^2(m+n)}+\frac{1}{2m^2n(m+n)}\right)=\sum_{m,n\in \Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2m^2n^2}.$$
This proves that
$$S_2=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}\big(\zeta(2)\big)\big(\zeta(2)\big)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)^2=\frac{\pi^4}{72}.$$

Now, for $S_1$, we see that the last term is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{8n^4}=\frac{1}{8}\zeta(4)=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{\pi^4}{90}\right)=\frac{\pi^4}{720}.$$
We are left with the first term, which is
$$\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{2mn(m+n)^2}=\zeta(3,1)=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(4)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\pi^4}{90}\right)=\frac{\pi^4}{360},$$
by Robert Z's answer.  Thus,
$$S_1=\frac{\pi^4}{360}-\frac{\pi^4}{720}=\frac{\pi^4}{720}.$$

Combining the two results above, we have
$$S=S_1+S_2=\frac{\pi^4}{720}+\frac{\pi^4}{72}=\frac{11\pi^4}{720}=\frac{11}{8}\zeta(4).$$
[Here](http://javier.fresan.perso.math.cnrs.fr/mzv.pdf) is another great resource to learn about the multiple zeta function.  Corollary 1.64 on page 26 and discussions that lead to this corollary are important to this problem.

---

Here is an elementary way to show that $\zeta(3,1)=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(4)$.  Recall that
$$\zeta(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_t)=\sum_{\substack{{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_t\in\Bbb{N}_1} \\{n_1>n_2>\ldots>n_t}}} \frac{1}{n_1^{s_1}n_2^{s_2}\cdots n_t^{s_t}}.$$
First, observe that
$$\frac{1}{m^2n^2}=\frac{1}{(m+n)^2n^2}+\frac{1}{(m+n)^2m^2}+\frac{2}{(m+n)^3m}+\frac{2}{(m+n)^3n}.$$
Taking the sum of the expression above over $m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1$, we get
$$\big(\zeta(2)\big)^2=\zeta(2,2)+\zeta(2,2)+2\zeta(3,1)+2\zeta(3,1)=2\big(\zeta(2,2)+2\zeta(3,1)\big),\tag{1}$$
so
$$\zeta(2,2)+2\zeta(3,1)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\zeta(2)\big)^2=\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4).$$
Now, note that
$$\frac{5}{2}\zeta(4)=\big(\zeta(2)\big)^2=\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}=\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\frac{1}{n^4}+\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m>n}}}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}+\sum_{\substack{{m,n\in\Bbb{N}_1}\\{m<n}}}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{5}{2}\zeta(4)=\zeta(4)+\zeta(2,2)+\zeta(2,2),$$
making
$$\zeta(2,2)=\frac{3}{4}\zeta(4).\tag{2}$$
Combining (1) and (2), we obtain
$$\zeta(3,1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4)-\zeta(2,2)\right)=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(4).$$

Comment: Nice. So finally we got the same result (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Partial Fractions gives
$$
\frac{m^2+n^2}{\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}=\frac{1/2}{(m-n)^2}+\frac{1/2}{(m+n)^2}\tag1
$$
First, we will compute
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{m,n=1\\m\ne n}}^\infty\frac1{mn(m-n)^2}
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty\frac1{mn(m-n)^2}\tag{2a}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{(m+n)nm^2}\tag{2b}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{m+n}\right)\frac1{m^3}\tag{2c}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{m+n}\right)\frac1{nm^2}\tag{2d}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{m+n}\right)\frac{m+n}{nm^3}\tag{2e}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^2n^2}\tag{2f}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\pi^4}{36}\tag{2g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: symmetry between $m\lt n$ and $n\lt m$
$\text{(2b)}$: substitute $m\mapsto m+n$
$\text{(2c)}$: partial fractions
$\text{(2d)}$: swap $m$ and $n$ in $\text{(2b)}$ then partial fractions
$\text{(2e)}$: average $\text{(2c)}$ and $\text{(2d)}$
$\text{(2f)}$: simplify
$\text{(2g)}$: evaluate $\zeta(2)^2$

Next, we will compute
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{mn(m+n)^2}
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\color{#C00}{\frac1{nm^2(n+m)}}-\color{#090}{\frac1{m^2(n+m)^2}}\right)\tag{3a}\\
&=\color{#C00}{\frac{\pi^4}{72}}-\color{#090}{\frac{\pi^4}{120}}\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\pi^4}{180}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: partial fractions
$\text{(3b)}$: the red sum is $\frac12$ of $\text{(2b)}$, the green sum is $\frac12\left(\zeta(2)^2-\zeta(4)\right)$
$\text{(3c)}$: simplify

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{m,n=1\\m\ne n}}^\infty\frac1{mn(m+n)^2}
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{mn(m+n)^2}-\frac14\zeta(4)\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac{\pi^4}{180}-\frac{\pi^4}{360}\tag{4b}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{\pi^4}{360}\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: subtract the terms where $m=n$
$\text{(4b)}$: apply $\text{(3c)}$
$\text{(4c)}$: simplify

Thus.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{m,n=1\\m\ne n}}^\infty\frac{m^2+n^2}{mn\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}
&=\frac12\frac{\pi^4}{36}+\frac12\frac{\pi^4}{360}\tag{5a}\\
&=\frac{11\pi^4}{720}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: apply $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(4)$
$\text{(5b)}$: simplify

Comment: If we don't evaluate the zeta functions, the answer above comes to $\frac12\zeta(2)^2+\frac18\zeta(4)$.