# An intriguing relationship between pairs of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

For $n\in\mathbb N$, define $$I_n:=\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln^n(\sin x)\ln^n(\cos x)\ \mathrm dx,\\ J_n:=\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln^n(\sin x)\ln^n(\cos x)\ \mathrm dx.$$
Then it appears numerically that $J_n=\dfrac\pi4I_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

> Is there a way to prove that?

Note that at least for $n=1,2$, there are [closed forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332041/22656) 
$$I_1=\frac{\pi}{2} \,\left (\ln ^2(2) -\frac{\pi^2}{24}\right),\ I_2=\frac{\pi}{2} \,\left (\ln ^4(2)+\frac{\pi^4}{160}-\ln(2)\zeta(3)\right).$$

Comment: Have you tried changing $\pi/2$ by a random number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By changing $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-u$ in $J_n$, we find $$J_n=\frac\pi2I_n-J_n$$ the claim follows directly.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, so easy...