# Prove $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left ( 1+\sqrt{1-x^2} \right ) \ln(1+x)}{ x} \text{d}x =-\frac{5}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I recently got an integral accidently($\zeta(s)$ is Riemann $\zeta$ function),
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left ( 1+\sqrt{1-x^2}  \right ) \ln(1+x)}{
x} \text{d}x
=-\frac{5}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln(2),
$$
which seems slightly harmonious. So I put it here to ask for an elegant proof for the integral. Besides, let $\operatorname{Li}_n(z)$ be polylogarithms, do similar expressions hold true for
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left ( 1+\sqrt{1-x^2}  \right ) 
\operatorname{Li}_n(x)}{
x} \text{d}x
$$
and $$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln\left ( 1+\sqrt{1-x^2}  \right ) 
\operatorname{Li}_n(-x)}{
x} \text{d}x?
$$
Thanks for helping and enlightening me.

Comment: May I ask where did you find this result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/890373/1104384

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks very much. That's probably what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and then utilize $2\ln a \ln b= \ln^2 a+\ln^2b -\ln^2\frac ab$ to break up the integrand
\begin{align}
I=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln( 1+\sqrt{1-x^2}  ) \ln(1+x)}{
x} {d}x\\
= &\int_0^1 \frac{4t \ln\frac2{1+t^2}\bigg(\ln2+\ln\frac{(1+t)^2}{2(1+t^2)}\bigg)}{1-t^4}dt\\
=&\int_0^1 \frac{2 t \left( 2\ln2 \ln\frac2{1+t^2}+ \ln^2\frac2{1+t^2}+\ln^2\frac{(1+t)^2}{2(1+t^2)}-\ln^2\frac{(1+t)^2}{4}\right)}{1-t^4}dt\\
\end{align}
where the four resulting integrals are evaluated below
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{4 t  \ln2 \ln\frac2{1+t^2}}{1-t^4}{dt}
\overset{t^2\to t} = 2  \ln2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac2{1+t}}{1-t^2}{dt}
= \frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln2\\
\\
 &\int_0^1 \frac{2 t  \ln^2\frac2{1+t^2}}{1-t^4}{dt}
\overset{t^2\to \frac{1-t}{1+t}} =  \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{2t}{dt}
= \frac{1}{8}\zeta(3)\\ 
\\
 &\int_0^1 \frac{2 t  \ln^2\frac{(1+t)^2}{2(1+t^2)}}{1-t^4}{dt}
\overset{t\to \frac{1-\sqrt t}{1+\sqrt t}} =  \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{4t}- \frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{2(1+t)}\ {dt}\\
&\hspace{40mm}= \frac{1}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac1{6}\ln^32\\ 
\\
 &\int_0^1 \frac{2 t \ln^2\frac{(1+t)^2}{4}}{1-t^4}dt
=\int_0^1 \frac{4t\ln^2\frac{1+t}2}{1+t^2}+ \frac{4t\ln^2\frac{1+t}2}{1-t^2}\ dt\\
&\hspace{35mm}= \left( \frac{7}{6}\ln^32 -\frac{\pi^2}{24}\ln2\right)+\left(\frac12\zeta(3)-\frac{4}{3}\ln^32\right) 
\end{align}
As a result
$$I=-\frac{5}{16}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2$$

Comment: I have never seen that $\ln$ identity. It's very nice!